# Simple Javascript question

Tags: javascript, syntax

I have `products : offer_id` in javascript and am getting value of offer_id dynamically.

Let say I get `products : 12345` but now instead of that I want it to be as `products : ;12345`, than how can this be achieved in javascript.

I have tried :

1. `products : ';'.offer_id`
2. `products : ';'."offer_id"`
3. `products : ';'.'offer_id'`
4. `products : ";".offer_id`

But all of my above trials have failed and am getting syntax error for each one of those. I am newbie to Javascript and so would really appreciate any inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP the concatenation character is <kbd>.</kbd> but in JavaScript is <kbd>+</kbd>

```
products : ';'+offer_id
```

Comment: @DavidMurdoch. PHP is ... interesting.